# Feh will not show black

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I am using feh to show a slideshow on my Raspberry Pi, specifically feh -Y -x -q -D black -F -Z -r /slideshow/. It works perfectly except that it won’t show the color black. Any way to fix this without changing all of the jpg files to an off black color?

Comment: what color does it show instead?

Comment: It replaces all of the black with white

Comment: what does `black` does after the `-D`?